# removeClass(myclass) with duration not working

Tags: jquery, css

This is my code to run it slow

```
if ($('body').hasClass('myclass')) {
  $('body').removeClass("myclass", "slow");

} else {
  $("body").addClass('myclass');
}
```

This code for sidebar menu to show and hide, It show smoothly but closing quickly, How to do this with close slowly?

**NOTE** 
: This css will work, but in this case it cannot be applied. Need jquery method.

```
transition-duration:1s;
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: you mean when you are adding `myclass` the sidebar is closing...?

Comment: the sidebar is closing is fine, but closing quickly but opening fine, i need to slow down using jquery removeclass / animate.

Comment: @teashark add the transition to the sidebar element directly not to the class that is being toggled. Check my answer for further details.

Comment: `$("body").css("transition-duration", "1s").toggleClass("myclass");`

Comment: @connexo: This sounds useful, but can removeclass instead toggle?

Comment: Well what more do you need to solve it by yourself now?

Comment: toggleClass not working, that is why using removeclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) to achieve that. Jquery UI extends Jquery's removeClass with speed and animation addition. You can apply 'easeInBack' easing for example.

```
$('body').removeClass('myclass', 'easeInBack');
```

You can find full documentation about remove class in Jquery-UI documentation there : http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/

Added Later:

**Jquery Way**

If you never used Jquery UI or/and not looking forward to use it you can achieve this with code below. But body will have `display:none;` at the end. I think you use body in code for simpler question. I don't know how you use this things actually but that code will help you catching the main idea.

```
$('.menu').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass('myclass');
});
```

Comment: Are you implemented Jquery UI with at least "Effects Core" and "Fade Effect" in "Effects" tab in download page?

Comment: i have put the script  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> for Jquery UI, will this fine to work this? not tried to download

Comment: It will work. Remember you need to implement Jquery UI after Jquery. If you download you can also customize it.

Comment: after implementing this after jquery code, the above code seems to work, but when click to close, it closes and opens then closes...! any idea? any conflict?

Comment: I mean add `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>` after `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: If you add `$('body').removeClass('myclass', 'easeInBack');` don't forget to remove your code `$('body').removeClass("myclass", "slow");`

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
            $(".myclass").removeClass("myclass");
        }, 2200 , "ease-out");

it is working perfectly instead removeclass, but closing after the delay, Did you get any idea to slow from this code/ animate option....etc

Comment: Just remove 2200. It is delaying the animation by 2,2 seconds.

Comment: ya i know , but the ease-out not working , that is why i put setTimeout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163780/discussion-between-teashark-and-yusuf-kandemir).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show and hide a sidebar and are doing so by toggling a class there is a small trick involved in this.

The trasition should be on the class that will never be removed. Example:

```
<nav class="mymenu">
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.mymenu {
   transform: translateX(-100%);
   transition: all 0.5s;
}

.mymenu.open {
   transform: none;
}
```

Notice the open class will be added or removed in jQuery/JS , but the .mymenu class will always be there. **The trick is in the CSS** !

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:**

- jQuery [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) does not support delays, you can either pass `classname / Multiple classnames/ A function that evaluates to a classname`.

Comment: .delay() will delay the execution of a function , it will not aid in transition. https://api.jquery.com/delay/